# Find oldest files/directories in file system up to 50 TB

Tags: linux, find

I need to find the oldest files with their associated directories in a 90 TB file system up to 50 TB and then move them to another file system.  They have to retain their directory structure as that is what identifies what the files are.  So -

first level/second level/third level/(file)

is the structure.  I need to move that entire structure - there isn't anything in the top level directories but without them I cannot identify what the file belongs to as all of the files that I am looking for have the same name.  When the process is complete I should have roughly 40 TB in the original file system left and almost nothing in the new file system left as the oldest files in the original are now there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

With GNU tools and `rsync`, you could do:

```
export LC_ALL=C # force tools to regard those file paths as arrays
                # of bytes (as they are in effect) and not do fancy
                # sorting (and use English for error/warning messages 
                # as an undesired side effect).

find . -type f -printf '%T@/%s/%p\0' | # print mtime/size/path
  sort -zn | # numerical sort, oldest first
  awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -F / -v max=50e12 '
    {total_size += $2}
    total_size > max {exit}
    {
      sub("^[^/]*/[^/]*/", "") # remove mtime/size/
      print # path
    }' |
  rsync -nv -aHAX0 --files-from=- --remove-source-files . /dest/dir/
```

(untested. The `-n` is for dry-run. Remove if happy).

Note that we're calculating the cumulative file size based on the file sizes (`%s`, replace with `%b` for the disk usage in sectors (and change to `total_size += $2 * 512`) and ignoring hard links. Those files, when copied to the target file system, along with the directories that contain them will likely end up using more than 50TB (unless there's file system compression or deduplication in play).

Comment: Better answer answer than mine (although I'd have added a `total_size > max { exit 0 }` to the awk script)

Comment: @symcbean, good point! I've added it now. Thanks.

Comment: This looks great!!  One questions though - I am assuming that the "max=50e12" portion of the awk statement is dictating to the system that we want 50 TB so based on extra folders (as there are two for each file) if I needed to i could reduce that "50" to "49" and that would equal 49 TB?

Comment: @JTelep, that's scientific notation. 50e12 is 50 times 10 to the power of 12 so 50TB (not 50TiB, for which you'd need `50 * 2^40`). You could also change it to `total_size += $2 + overhead` where `overhead` is defined as the overhead incurred by those folders. See also `%k` instead of `%s` to get the disk usage in KiB.

Answer (score 2):

The 'ls' command is somewhat creative with timestamps - so parsing them can be a pain. It would probably be a lot easier to implement this in a language which implements [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)(). Some versions of Unix have a [command line stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) - on a nearby RH box:

```
 find ${BASEDIR} -type f -exec stat --format="%y %b %n" {} \; | sort | less
```

But this will run like a dog with a large number of files.

The documentation for GNU awk includes an [example extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Internal-File-Description.html#Internal-File-Description) providing filesystem functions, but you would need to do some work to build and maintain this.

Writing a program from scratch in PHP, C or Perl (or go, ruby or many other languages) would be straightforward but beyond the scope of a post here.

Comment: Note that that GNU `stat` was added long after GNU `find` had a `-printf` command (that can do the same as GNU `stat` with a much better interface).